# Bootstrap modal close through js bug

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, vue-component

How do I close bootstap modal programmatically? I checked so many answers about it, but none of them work... All below methods close modal, but keeps backdrop of it so I tried to remove backdrop with `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` it breaks modal and if I show it after removing backdrop scroll doesn't work on modal. I need to close it through js and whenever I want to by calling method. I know I can use `data-dismiss="modal"` to close it.

how I'm hiding modal:

```
$('#mymodal').modal("toggle");
$('#mymodal').modal("hide");
$('.close').click();
```

**Update**

So I see that for a lot of people it works with `$('#mymodal').modal("hide");` but when I Inspect page I can see that there is two modal-backdrops in the body and after I call hide it closes modal and first modal-backdrop, but second one stays and this is why it's not working.

with modal open:

[image]

After closing modal with `$('#mymodal').modal("hide");`

[image]

Comment: I think there's a problem how you implemented the modal HTML try doing it with the sample code from bootstrap and check if you get the same results. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modal-components

Answer (score 0):

This should work. if not you have other problem in code. Read modal javascript docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Comment: it closes modal, but doesn't close modal-backdrop check my updated question

Comment: Do you use latest bootstrap 4 version?

Comment: I use 4.3.1 bootstrap